# Converting some datetime columns in my SQL Server database to date columns. Is it advisable from a product persp.?

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012 introduced the `Date` data type for a column, prior to that we only had the `DateTime` data type so many columns (like `Birthdate`) were also stored with a time which was then been stripped off with some logic in the web code.

My question: is it advisable to change these `DateTime` columns to `Date` columns as my application database is on SQL Server 2012? I know that I will have to put in migration scripts and handle the web side for any conversion functions written on such columns.

Please provide your inputs as this will be a huge change for my product.

Comment: Actually, the `Date` data type was introduced in 2008 version.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends on the field you want to change...
As you said for fields like birth date it is ok to change it from datetime to date..
For fields like created datetime and updated datetime it is not good idea to change data type...
To make change in datatype figureout how much time it will take to change your business login because of it.
if its feasible for you and if you can absorb that much time go for it

It will increase your processing speed and might save some disc space.